# How to capture text and replace it simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to look through a string and extract the names of the following form: `"$name$"` (with no spaces). I want to extract the name (without the "$"s) and then replace the name with a number. So for example, I want to do something along the lines of the following:

```py
raw_string = "Hello $tim$ my name is $sam$ I'll call you $tim$"
m = re.compile(r"\$(\S+)\$")
```

to end up with something like this

```py
names          # { "tim": 0, "sam": 1 }
parsed_string  # "Hello $0$ my name is $1$ I'll call you $0$"
```

Is there a better or more efficient way to do this without doing it in two steps using `re.search()` or `re.findall()` and then `re.sub()`?

Can you perform a sub on a `Match Object` in place?

Or would it be more efficient to just do two passes, to find all the matches and then replace them?

Sorry if this is a repeat question, I didn't find any solutions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The regex would be `\$(.+?)\$` so you would loop the matches, store and count `\1` in a dictionary, loop the dictionary, and perform a literal replace of the name surrounded by dollar signs.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to perform the match and the replace in one step? Or do you know which is the most efficient (or most pythonic) way to do this – in one step (match and replace at the same time) or in two (find all the matches and then replace them all)?

Comment: You can perform a sub on `re.Match`, but it doesn't quite work the way you envisioned.  For example, the first `$tim$` would not have the same match as the second `$tim$`.

Comment: No clue, I'm not a Python developer. Just program what I described and benchmark it. I don't know what it means to be "Pythonic" but I do know that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/103990)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus haha fair enough. I guess I should say that I _do_ already have a working version that achieves the result in two passes (like you said). But I'm not a python pro, so I'm just curious about what method would achieve this result in a way that works most fluidly with the way the python regular expressions library is implemented.

Comment: I see. In light of that information you should try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Okay gotcha, sorry I'm still kind of new to Stack Exchange in general. Is it still off-topic for Stack Overflow if I'm looking for a way to do the match and replace in one pass? And I can take out the part of my question that asks about what is best practice / most efficient – if that's more of a question for code review. Thanks for your help and for your patience!

Comment: If you have a working solution then you should have presented it first. If you have an issue with your current solution then that should have been declared. If the issue is that a seemingly innocuous operation takes 60 seconds when you expect it to take .0025 seconds then it would probably be well-received here but asking about Pythonic-ness without good reason is much better suited for the other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Combining match and replace

There's no function that I'm aware of (even in PyPi regex library) that allows you to both capture and replace simultaneously. What you mean by *most pythonic*, no one knows (it's opinion-based), but, I think this is a clean way to accomplish this in python without having to do both a find (`re.search` or `re.findall`) and replace (`re.sub`).

#### Conditional replacements

Conditional replacements are not possible without a callback as you're replacing your text with different values. Yes, you could create a for loop and find every instance of `\$([^$]+)\$`, but then you run into a new issue: You can't replace duplicate instances with the same digit without using additional logic (second instance of `$tim$` would become `$2$` instead of `$0`).

Then someone might think of backreferences. Since a backreference only works *after* the text has been captured, you cannot replace your multiple instances of `$tim$` with `$0$` without first having located each of them in the string. Backreferences won't work because the group they reference must have a match prior to using the backreference, otherwise it's set to an empty string: `\1(.)` only matches one character since `\1` is a backreference to capture group 1 that is currently set to no match; whereas `(.)\1` will match two characters.

At this point, we might want to default back to two method calls for searching and replacing. But there's one neat little way of accomplishing this: callback.

---

#### Using a callback

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by using a callback in `re.sub`. You still have to add logic for duplicate instances, but it's much better than making a call to two different methods for matching and replacing.

```
import re

names = {}
def repl(m):
    n = m.group(1)
    if n not in names:
        names[n]=len(names)
    return "$"+str(names[n])+"$"

s = "Hello $tim$ my name is $sam$ I'll call you $tim$"
r = re.compile(r'\$([^$]+)\$')
s = re.sub(r,repl,s)

print(names)
print(s)
```

Result:

```
{'tim': 0, 'sam': 1}
Hello $0$ my name is $1$ I'll call you $0$
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, using regex here might not be the best answer as the multiple matches of `$tim$` wouldn't carrying the same instance over the text.  Normally in these cases you want to replace a `%0` or similar with the actual texts of `tim`, but given that you *do* mean to get your desired result, then you would need to do some extra handling to get the keys to correspond:

```
import re

text = "Hello $tim$ my name is $sam$ I'll call you $tim$"
pat = re.compile(r'\$(.+?)\$')

# create a dictionary based on the first occurred index of the matched group
map_keys = {k: str(v) for v, k in list(enumerate(pat.findall(text)))[::-1]}

map_keys
# {'tim': '0', 'sam': '1'}
```

Once you have built that, you could do a `re.sub` with a custom function:

```
result = pat.sub(lambda x: '${}$'.format(map_keys.get(x.groups()[0])), text)

result
# "Hello $0$ my name is $1$ I'll call you $0$"
```

Notice this is not optimal as you would need to recreate the `$` placeholders to match your desired text.

Comment: `[^$]+` is more efficient than `.+?` since it doesn't backtrack.